# Spring + Thymeleaf - How to make e multiple select selected

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

I have two entities mapped with a ManyToMany annotation and data saving works as expected, the problem is I cannot make the multiple select to show the correct selected options.

In my template I have:

```
<div class="form-select col-sm-10">
    <select th:field="*{addresses}" class="form-control" multiple="multiple">
        <option th:each="a : ${addresses}"
        th:value="${a.addressId}" th:text="${a.addressName}">Opzione</option>

    </select>
</div>
```

It's the same snippet I use for single select that correctly show the selected element, but it does not work for multiple.

The ManyToMany annotation is made in this way

```
@Entity
public class User {

@ManyToMany
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

//getters and setters

}

@Entity
public class Address {

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.REMOVE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}, mappedBy = "addresses")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();

//getters and setters

}
```

In the controller i simply take the list of Address and add it to the model. I see the values in the select, the only thing it does not work is the selected on the correct options.
More of it, if I select on the edit page some new option, they correctly are saved

```
    @RequestMapping("/{userId}")
        public String getUser(@PathVariable long userId, ModelMap model) {
            User logged = authenticationFacade.getAuthenticatedUser();

            User user = service.findById(userId);
            UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
            List<Location> locations = locationService.findAllLocations();
        Iterable<Address> addresses = addressService.findByLocationInAndActiveIsTrue(locations);
        List<Address> addressList = new ArrayList<>();
        addresses.forEach(addressList::add);
        logger.debug("Gli address dell'utente sono: " + user.getAddresses());
        model.addAttribute("addresses", addressList);
        model.addAttribute("user", dto);
        model.addAttribute("edit", true);
        model.addAttribute("pageTitle", user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
        model.addAttribute("userProfiles", userProfiles);
        model.addAttribute("realUser", user);

        return "admin/backuser";
    }
```

Comment: can you share controller code

Comment: Added, thanks, i simply add the list to the model

Comment: please add whole controller or at least handler method

Comment: I added the whole controller, thank you, just to say that the addresses are correctly saved in the DB, it's just a matter of view, we cannot see the "selected" items